# textarea element's scrollbar covers the border

Tags: css, angular, twitter-bootstrap, textarea, scrollbar

I am trying to add border color to textarea when the characters are more than 4000, however the scrollbar is displayed over the textarea borders. This green border color appears only when clicking on the textarea, but I can't find any `focus` property in the CSS. Any idea how to fix this?

I tried adding top borders to the scrollbar but it didn't work. The project is using bootstrap.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use for style focus

```
textarea:focus {
    outline: none !important;
    border:1px solid red;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #719ECE;
}
```

Also check example to more clear  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-textarea